# Transforming network graph to another structure

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have an edge-list represent a graph network like below:

Input : **[(A,1),(A,2),(B,1)(B,2)(C,2)(C,3)]**

What would be the optimal way to transform it to the following list:

Output : **[(A,B,2),(B,C,1),(A,C,1)]** .In the Output list, entries represent 2 nodes and a similarity measure over the other set of nodes.

the Input list represents the 1st graph from the following figure, and the Output list represents the association among nodes(graph 2 in the figure).

[image]

Here is what I did, I used self join on the input list and tried to count the entries for calculating edge value.

But, In that case, I am getting lots of redundant entries(because of the join) and It is not effective when I have lots of data.

Self Join is like : (A,1),(B,1) gives (A,1, B) as I am joining on the number node. and after that, I have to count the same results to get the edge value

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We don't answer questions with no attempt and no code, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ohh, pardon me for that and thank you for mentioning the "How to ask document". Here is what I did, I used self join on the input list and tried to count the entries for calculating edge value. But, In that case, I am getting lots of redundant entries(because of the join) and It is not effective when I have lots of data.

Comment: Self Join is like : (A,1),(B,1) gives (A,1, B) as I am joining on the number node. and after that, I have to count the same results to get the edge value

Comment: Can you edit your question and include this information in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the information you want by building a list of all letter-vertices connected to every number-vertex; then for every pair of letter-vertices present in the same list, add 1 to a similarity counter for that pair.

I used a standard `dict` with the `.setdefault` method to store the lists of letter-vertices connected to every number-vertex in `adjacency_dict`.

I used a `defaultdict` to store the similarity counts in `sim_dict`. The choice between `dict` + `setdefault` or `defaultdict` is entirely a matter of taste; since there were two dicts in my code, I used one of each to showcase their ease of use. As for my personal taste, I like `dict.setdefault` when the dict holds mutables (such as lists) and I prefer `defaultdict` when the dict holds non-mutables (such as ints). Note that since `sim_dict` is holding counts, using a `Counter` would also have been appropriate.

To find all possible pairs of letter-vertices present in a same list, I used `itertools.combinations` along with `sorted` to make sure that combinations are always in alphabetical order - so that `('A', 'C')` cannot be treated as a different pair than `('C', 'A')`.

```py
import itertools    # combinations
import collections  # defaultdict

edge_list = [('A',1),('A',2),('B',1),('B',2),('C',2),('C',3)]

adjacency_dict = {}
for letter,num in edge_list:
  adjacency_dict.setdefault(num, []).append(letter)

print(adjacency_dict)
# {1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 3: ['C']}

sim_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for l in adjacency_dict.values():
  for a,b in itertools.combinations(sorted(l), 2):
    sim_dict[(a,b)] += 1

print(sim_dict)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('A', 'B'): 2, ('A', 'C'): 1, ('B', 'C'): 1})

sim_list = [(a,b,s) for (a,b),s in sim_dict.items()]

print(sim_list)
# [('A', 'B', 2), ('A', 'C', 1), ('B', 'C', 1)]
```

Relevant documentation:

- [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault);
- [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict);
- [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter);
- [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).